# PHP method to determine if an array exists within an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a php array method that can tell me if an array has arrays as its values without doing a foreach loop?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a foreach loop? Most likely an answer that involves a built-in function will do more work than you just creating a foreach loop to do this then toss it in a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

print_r(array_filter($array, "is_array"));

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_filter`

```
$array = array(1,array(),2);
                     ^--------------- array in array

if(array_filter($array,"is_array"))
{
    // I found some arrays
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Id choose you since you used it in an if statement, but its pretty much the same as the other one.